# jQuery Mobile: Alternative to List View

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need a way to display my content, but I'm not sure that a listview is the way to go because I have >500 elements that change dynamically the refresh lags a bit. Any other good options I should consider?

Specifically, I have a bunch of names and I need the user to pick one...which leads to a different group of names. I have a search filter at the top..which is primarily what the user will be using. I need to make this look good!

Let me know if this is the wrong place for this...

Comment: Probably you want split this >500 elements between different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is not to display 500 choices, users wont be interested in visually searching that.
Try auto-complete (ie wait for at least 2 chars and show matching) or if you want a non-keyboard option maybe break the list into alphabetic chunks, eg A-E, F-J, etc.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention that my listview has a search filter at the top. Is it possible to display the matches from an autocomplete as a list view, without displaying the whole list to begin with?

Comment: Don't load the list until the user has entered two (for example) characters.  How you do this will depend on how you implemented the auto-complete.

Comment: Cool idea. I need help doing that though, I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720816/jquery-mobile-listview-filter-search-callback-function

Answer (score 0):

You can show tabs after search box you have.

Say 1.Recent 2.alpha order 3. if you have any category.

Also if you are getting data from web services or you have control over data source it would be better if you can show one time say 50 items in list and then show more button at bottom this will improve you app performance.